# Script to Process txt file to CSV

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I am trying/attempting to write a script to turn this:

```
Mikrotik01#show unique routing entry | 192.168.255.232 | inc ID
Thu June 10 15:21:32.808 CST
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.21
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.233
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.155
Mikrotik01#show unique routing entry | 192.168.255.233 | inc ID
Thu June 10 15:21:33.079 CST
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.234
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.232
Mikrotik01#show unique routing entry | 192.168.255.234 | inc ID
Thu June 10 15:21:33.347 CST
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.233
 Unique Entry: 192.168.255.235
```

Into a CSV that contains:

```
192.168.255.232,192.168.255.21,192.168.255.233,192.168.255.155
192.168.255.233,192.168.255.234,192.168.255.232
192.168.255.234,192.168.255.233,192.168.255.235
```

Basically it will start a new row with the first line then add each of the neighboring
router ID on the same line with a comma until it reaches the next line that contains the
"Mikrotik" hostname where it would create a new line and continue through the whole file.
End result in a csv.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]|]+' '
    /^Mikrotik01/ {if (NR>1) print ""; printf "%s", $(NF-2)} 
    /Unique Entry/ {printf ",%s", $NF}
    END {print ""}
' file.txt > File.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In first close it can be `sed`-script:

```
sed -E '
/Mikrotik01/{s/.* ([0-9.]{7,}) .*/\1/;x;/^$/!b}
/[0-9.]{7,}/!d
s/.* ([0-9.]{7,}).*/\1/
x
G
s/\n/,/
h
$!d' file.txt > file.csv
```

Or (may be shorter a little but not so strong - it recognize new line block by `|` not by `Mikrotik01`)

```
sed -E '
  /^T/d
  s/^[^.]*[|:] //
  / \|.*$/{s///;x;/^$/!b}
  x
  G
  s/\n/,/
  $!{h;d}' file.txt > file.csv
```

It can be simplified (because I do twice same `x` and `s/`) but right now I can't imagine how.